# Finding integer representation as difference of two triangular numbers

Tags: nt.number-theory, algorithms, factorization

Since $n = \frac{n(n+1)}{2}-\frac{n(n-1)}{2}$, every natural number can be represented as the difference of two triangular numbers:
$ n = \frac{a(a+1)}{2}-\frac{b(b-1)}{2}$. Finding such a representation gives a factorization of $n = \frac{(a+b)\cdot(a-b+1)}{2}$.
A naive way of finding such representations would be to set

$x = floor(0.5+\sqrt{0.25+2n})$

```
while True:
  x = x+1
  set y = x(x+1)/2 -n
  if issquare(8*y+1):
      b = (1+sqrt(8*y+1))/2
      if x-b+1 = 0 (mod 2):
         return (x-b+1)/2,x+b
      else:
         return x-b+1,(x+b)/2
```

Although to me unclear why this algorithm should terminate, I have implemented it in python and the running time for $n=p\cdot q$ with two unequal primes $p$ and $q$ seems to be $n^{0.38} < n^{0.5} = \sqrt{n}$, which seems to be better than trial division.
It is known, that one can find very fast a representation of $n$ as a sum of three triangular numbers by first finding a representation of $8n+3$ as a sum of three squares using the algorithm of Shallit and Rabin.
So in essence I have two questions:

1) Does anybody know a reason why the above naive algorithm should terminate.

2) Does anybody know of a faster way to find such (nontrivial) representation of $n$ without factoring $n$ first?

Comment: This is just a minor variant of Fermat's method, but using triangular numbers instead of squares: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermat%27s_factorization_method

Comment: I know of Fermat's factorization method. This method is different.

Comment: But what you are doing is equivalent to writing $8n = (2a+1)^{2}- (2b-1)^{2}$.

Comment: I know that, but I thought, that somebody might know of a faster way to find such representation. Thanks for your comment.

Comment: What range of $n$ did you examine to estimate your 0.38 exponent?

Comment: I choose 1000 random pair of primes $p, q$ not equal each with 6 digits and measured the steps in the loop, for example: $p=108571,q=102329,n=11109961859,steps=7552$ In this case the exponent is $log(7552)/log(n) = 0.28631$

Comment: Every method to factor an uneven number is equivalent to Fermat's method: $2n+1=d\cdot e = ((d+e)/2)^2-((d-e)/2)^2$

Comment: This is not an answer but I am not allowed to comment yet ( and I apologize). my question is: can you please show how your method can factor the triangular number N=8*17=136? I tried finding two triangular numbers whose difference was N=136 and couldn't. I then tried to go backward from factors 8*17,2*68,4*34 to (a,b) setting a+b=2*17 and a-b+1=8...and I run into a problem. the only way to go backward is to use a+b=136 and a-b+1=1. And this may be interesting because it looks like triangular numbers have their own "primes". (I will delete my answer once your respond to my question)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The representations of this type correspond one-for-one to odd divisors of $n$. So your request for a method for constructing such a representation without factoring seems to be hopeless: if you have a method for constructing such a representation it is automatically a method for factoring. See [Wikipedia: Polite number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polite_number).

Answer (score 1):

There is a quick way to find solutions even without (completely) factoring. In particular, write $2n = 2^{\alpha} m$, where $m$ is odd and use the factorization $2n = m \cdot 2^{\alpha}$ to find $a$ and $b$. This gives
$$
a = \frac{2^{\alpha} + m - 1}{2}, \quad b = \frac{|2^{\alpha} - m| + 1}{2},
$$
which always results in a non-trivial solution unless $n$ is a power of $2$ (in which case it is well-known that there is no representation of $n$ as the sum of a set of consecutive integers of size $> 1$).

Answer (score 0):

For 2) it is possible to get subexponential time.

If $n$ is prime there are few representations.

So you want $2n=(a+b)(a-b+1)$ in nontrivial way.

Factor $2n$ in subexponential time and for all divisors
$d$ of $2n$, write $2n=dd'$.

Solve $a+b=2d,a+b-1=d'$ to get 
$$a=d-1/2+d'/2,b=d+1/2-d'/2$$.

In case $a,b$ are integers, you have found representation.

I wouldn't expect your approach to give efficient factoring algorithm.

Comment: I should say that finding the representation without factoring n or 2n first.

Comment: @stackExchangeUser Did you wrote that? I didn't notice it, maybe my mistake.

Comment: No I didn't write that, I thought it was clear from the context, my mistake.